# Is there a way to use Spring web flow to store flow data into persistent storage instead of sticking it to http session

Tags: spring-webflow

Is there a way to use Spring web flow to store flow data into persistent storage instead of sticking it to http session. I'm looking to find a way to store web flow data in some persistent storage. Each time request comes spring loads the flow data and when response is sent back flow data is stored back and later retrieved when request comes back again. Reason for this is my application is running in multiple data centers and support transactions around 500tps and I don't want to manage session data across different data centers.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for are implementations of [FlowExecutionListenerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/FlowExecutionListenerAdapter.html)

Out of the box SWF supports [HibernateFlowExecutionListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/persistence/HibernateFlowExecutionListener.html) and [JpaFlowExecutionListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/persistence/JpaFlowExecutionListener.html). If you want to use another db store you'd have to implement your own [FlowExecutionListenerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/FlowExecutionListenerAdapter.html).

see the swf config here: [Spring Web Flow and Spring MVC URL 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849070/spring-web-flow-and-spring-mvc-url-404) to see how it is initalized

**Note:** interface ends with `'Adapter'` impl classes end with `'Listener'`